# Is it possible to install scikit-learn on machine without internet and a custom path libraray?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

#### Test 1

I installed scikit-learn 0.23.2 on my virtual environement on **my local machine** (Windows) and uploaded to the content of the site-pakages to my second machine that does **not have access to internet**.
Since I don't have admin write permission on the default Lib/site-packages, I put the packages necessary for every project on project specific folder and then point to it on my python code.

Until now, I've managed to use python packages using the hack :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path_to_my_site-packages-folder")
import foo
```

When I did the same trick with scikit-learn packages, and tried to import it in my code, Python throws an error like this

[image]

#### Test 2

The second Test is the method suggested by @Sahil_Angra. In this test, I've downloaded the necessary packages (scikit-learn in this example) on my local machine and then uploaded the wheel files to the other machine. Then I installed the packages using the wheel files.

Step 1: Download wheels on local machine and store them in a folder

```
pip download scikit-learn==0.23.* -d 'path_to_folder_that_will_contain_wheel_files'
```

Step 2: Transfer the compressed folder to the machine without internet

```
tar cvfz dependencies.tar.gz 'path_to_folder_that_contain_downloaded_wheel_files'
```

Step 3: Install the package on the machine without internet

```
tar zxvfv dependencies.tar.gz  
cd dependencies 
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.* -f ./ --no-index --path 'path_of_custom_library_folder'
```

The installation went fine and no error message was shown. However I got the same error when I import something from sklearn in my Python code

#### Question

So I was wondering if this is due to the fact that Scikit-learn uses some Cython code and if there is a work around to solve the problem?

System information on local machine

> System: Windows
> Release: 10
> Version: 10.0.17134
> Machine: AMD64
> Python : 3.7.0
> pip : 19.1.1
> Compiler : MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)

System information on machine without internet

> System: Windows
> Release: 2008ServerR2
> Version: 6.1.7601
> Machine: AMD64
> Python : 3.7.1
> pip : 19.1.1
> Compiler : MSC V.1912 64 bit (AMD64)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Copying of contents of site-packages to the second machine bounds to give an error if all the relevant folders and files of the package are not copied.

For your issue, I would suggest downloading the .whl file (available on Pypi) for your package onto your system one. And sending the file over to system two and installing it using

```
pip install "path/filename.whl"
```

This would build the module from scratch and install it without any errors

Comment: Thanks  @Sahil_Angra for your response. I've tried the suggested method but I didn't work. I also edited my question since I forgot to mention that I'm install the packages in a specific custom library Path and not the default site-packages folder